# У меня кнопка находиться в input-е. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на input кнопка не уходила назад?

Tags: html, css

```css
  .main-btn{
        position: absolute;
        left: -20%;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-block:10px;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        background-color: blue;
        color: azure;
     }
     .footer-form-control{
        background-color: #efefef;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .footer-form-control:focus{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .footer-form-control:active{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .footer-form-control:focus .main-btn{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .footer-form-control:active .main-btn{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="footer-content-list footer-content-item desk-pad-left-30">
            
            <div class="footer-details mt-5 ms-3">
               
                <div class="footer-newsletter-form">
                    <form class="newsletter-form needs-validation" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group has-validation">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control footer-form-control" id="emails" name="EMAIL" required autocomplete="off">
                                <button class="btn main-btn footer-btn" type="submit">Signup</button>
                            
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Please enter  your email correctly.
                                </div>
                            
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Не хватает каких то стилей. Кнопка съезжает вниз и воспроизвести то, что на картинке не получается. Добавьте все необходимые стили, что бы можно было воспроизвести вашу проблему

Comment: Эм, кнопка не может находится в input-е.  Так что селектор `.footer-form-control:focus .main-btn` ничего не делает. Может вы хотели `.footer-form-control:focus + .main-btn`?